# How to parse a string into C++ typename?

Tags: c++, performance, typename

How to implement `atot()` so it uses `atof()`, `atoi()`, or `atol()` according to the type?
Currently it uses `atof()` for all types:

```
template<typename T>
T Mtx<T>::atot(const char *s) const
{
    return atof(s);
}
```

Please note that speed is very important.

Comment: What about specializing?

Comment: Why is it a member function? Do you want it to choose the function based on the type `T`?

Comment: @Nick, I don't know what it is. If this is a solution, please post it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: @sftrabbit, there is no special reason. I can make it static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straight-forward solution is to specialize:

```
template<>
double Mtx<double>::atot(const char *s) const
{
    return atof(s);
}

template<>
int Mtx<int>::atot(const char *s) const
{
    return atoi(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`boost::lexical_cast<T>` should do this, basically

```
template<typename T>
T Mtx<T>::atot(const char *s) const
{
    return boost::lexical_cast<T>(s);
}
```

Demo:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

template<typename T>
T atot(const char *s)
{
    return boost::lexical_cast<T>(s);
}

int main()
{
    auto i = atot<int>("3");
    auto d = atot<double>("-INF");
    auto f = atot<double>("314e-2");
    auto ul = atot<unsigned long>("65537");
}
```

Comment: lexical_cast may not fast enough compare to c function call?

Comment: @billz It may or may not. IIRC boost lexical_cast is specialized for builtin numeric types, and falls back to using _stream extraction_ if it doesn't have such a specialization. You might want to profile this, though.

Answer (score 3):

Specializing is creating special implementations of the template depending on a particular type.

In this case you could do this:

```
template<>
float Mtx<float>::atot(const char *s) const
{
    return atof(s);
}

template<>
int Mtx<int>::atot(const char *s) const
{
    return atoi(s);
}
```

... and so on

So if you use `atot` with `float` or with `int`, then the above implementations will be used. For any other type, the generic one you already have will be used.

Comment: This doesn't compile. But it does if I replace `T` by `float` and `int` respectively. Is it a typo?

Comment: @Serg, yup it was a typo :) fixed it

Answer (score 2):

I really don't get why you want this. It seems just as easy to call the right method.

But what about something like the following?

```
void atot(const char *s, float& result)
{
    result = atof(s);
}

void atot(const char *s, long& result)
{
    result = atol(s);
}

void atot(const char *s, int& result)
{
    result = atoi(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overload a function, if the type appears in one of the parameters. So you'll need an out parameter instead of the return value:

```
void atonum(const char*, int&);
void atonum(const char*, long&);
void atonum(const char*, float&);
```

If you don't like this, you can use template specialization. See other answers about this.

Or you can combine the overload with a wrapper template:

```
template<typename T> void atonum(const char* a)
{
    T tmp;
    atonum(a, tmp);
    return tmp;
}
```

But that's still as ugly to call as the specialized templates.

You can get a nicer syntax, for the caller, by overloading type conversion operators.
Proof of concept:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
struct atonum
{
    atonum(const char* a):m_a(a){}
    operator int(){printf("int\n"); return atoi(m_a);}
    operator long(){printf("long\n"); return atol(m_a);}
    operator float(){printf("float\n"); return atof(m_a);}
private:
    const char* m_a;
};
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int i = atonum("1");
    long l = atonum("2");
    float f = atonum("3.0");
    return i+l+f;
}
```